# WPF DataTemplate Binding BUG: AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: wpf, templates, exception, styles

Here are the DataTemplates:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:Item}" x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <Border/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:StyleItem}" x:Key="StyleItemTemplate">
    <Border>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Item}" 
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am trying to bind a `List<StyleItem>` to an ItemsControl,
setting `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StyleItemTemplate}"`, but then I get a [`System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx).

I read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a2fed790-ef1b-4aa8-b0aa-69fe9b2886e5/) post, and althoug the StyleItem and Item classes are not generic classes, anyhow; I don't know how to use the parenthsis solution in my situation.

The `Item` and `StyleItem` classes are generated EF entities that inherit from [`System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx), and implement [`System.ComponentModel.IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This smells like a collision between your `StyleItem.Item` property and the property indexer defined in `IDataErrorInfo`. Try changing the name of your `StyleItem.Item` property to something else.

Comment: You were efin right!!! you're good man, I was struggling a lot with this issue!
אתה המלך!

Comment: Who would have thought :) בבקשה!

Answer (score 0):

You should either use the x:Key property or the DataType property.

You must not use both. So remove either one to get it to work! I suggest removing the DataType property, since you already use the keys in your example!

Comment: Well I removed the DataType property and still doesn't work.
About removing the key, how do I refer to it if it doesn't have key?  
Did you test this and it works for you!? cuz for me it doesn't :'(

Comment: You do not need to refer to DataType. When you have a list or a ContentControl (like Button), WPF will check if there are any DataTemplates defined for the current DataContext and use that one.